# Adjective for someone who accepts all challenges

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What's the adjective for someone who accepts any challenge? Let's say a strong knight, who never says no to a challenge. Is there any adjective for it? Or what would be the best way to describe such trait? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Closest thing i can think of is:

**dauntless**

adjective   literary

UK  /ˈdɔːnt.ləs/ US  /ˈdɑːnt.ləs/

**showing determination and no fear:**

In spite of the scale of the famine, the relief workers struggled on with dauntless optimism.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dauntless

Comment: Or check out the synonyms for [dauntless](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/dauntless).

Answer (score 0):

The word I use for this is [game](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/game#cald4-2):

Who could we talk into jumping off this cliff?
Ask Gordon, he's always game.